# Which IDE is good for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, ide

Any one provide me best IDE for wordpress theme and plugin editing in windows. As I m new to this area, Please provide me suggestion.

Any I am using it in my notebook with 2GB RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've been using netbeans, and it works great, the bad thing: (it depends of your work maching) needs more resources

Answer (score -1):

For wordpress themes, I would like to suggest, Adobe Photoshop. And for the plugins, just Notepad++ will do.